# What did compiler do in this piece of code(Base class pointer to derived class object)?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

In this piece of code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class B
{
    int b;
    public:
    ~B(){ cout <<"B::~B()"<<endl; }//1
};

class D: public B
{
  int i,d,e,f;
  public:
  ~D() { cout <<"D::~D()"<<endl; }//2
};

int main(void)
{
    cout << "sizeB:" << sizeof(B) << " sizeD:"<< sizeof(D) <<endl;
    B *pb = new D[2];

    delete [] pb;

    return 0;
}
```

At the beginning, I dont know how delete[] work correctly. Then I notice this:

```
B* pb = new D[2];
&pb[1] - &pb[0] == sizeof(B)；

D* pd = new D[2];
&pb[1] - &pb[0] == sizeof(D)；
```

What did complier do? And why it worked like this?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? It isn't clear what exactly you are asking.

Comment: You're not showing the output; we can hardly explain why it works "like this" when we don't know what "like this" means.

Comment: In the second snippet of code, both variables are called "pd". The second pd will "shadow" the first. What happened there, then, is called a memory leak. The first "pd" is still there, still pointing to an array of 2x D, but you just can't reference it any more. So your second assignment creates a new variable and assigns it a new value.

Comment: @kfsone no, the second snippet is probably an example. It wouldn't compile otherwise.

Comment: The second snippet had a typo (notice that the second line uses `pb`, not `pd`). I have just fixed it.

Comment: @juanchopanza Sadly, it *will* compile under Visual Studio, I have to fix a lot of shadowed variables... I always compile with -Wall under GCC so I can never remember whether it is a default behavior or if it requires -Wshadow - but -Wshadow exists for a reason :)

Comment: @kfsone strange that it compiles. It is a re-declaration of `pb`. That should fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is UB here, since you are trying to `delete` array of type `B`, that has dynamic type `D`.

> n3376 5.3.4/3:
>
> In the second alternative (delete
> array) **if the dynamic type of the object to be deleted differs from its static type, the behavior is undefined**

Also, since you want to work polymorphycally - you should make `d-tor` of base class `virtual`.

Answer (score 3):

It is not at all clear what you are asking, but when you do this:

```
B* pb = new D[2];
```

you are dynamically allocating an array of `D` objects, and you are making a `B*` point to the first element. Here

```
D* pd = new D[2];
```

you are also allocating an array of `D` objects, and making a `D*` point to the first element.

All pointer arithmetic you perform on those pointers will be based on the size of `B` and `D` respectively. This is not what you want, since the size of `B` and `D` need not be the same.

To be clear: you do not have a *"base class pointer to derived class object"*, you have a base class pointer to an array of derived class objects.

It seems to me that what you really want is an array of *pointers* to `B`, which you can then point towards `B` or `D` objects, i.e. a polymorphic array.

Also note that you need to declare `B`'s destructor as virtual, as has been already pointed out.

Comment: Firstly, pb and pd point to the same address, and because sizeof(B)!=sizeof(D), so pb + sizeof(B) != pd + sizeof(D); but when I use delete[] pb. It calls B's destructor correctly.Should they point to different address and cause error??

Comment: @elinx you should fix your question, because there is nothing in it which explains why `pb` and `pd` point to the same address.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you would need the destructor of `B` to be `virtual` in order to avoid undefined behaviour (UB) when you try to delete a `D` object through a `B` pointer.

But even in this case, you would be the victim of an unfortunate feature of C++, inherited from C. That is: arrays seem to work polymorphically, but they don't.

STL containers protect you against this pitfall. For instance:

```
std::vector<B> = std::vector<D>(2); // Illegal
```

But this is not the case with arrays. Your example compiles, but then strange things happen because you really have an array of `D`, but use it through a `B*`. Pointer arithmetic fails because the runtime thinks it has an array of `B` instead of `D`, and `delete[]` fails again because the runtime thinks it has to delete an array of `B` instead of `D`. Oh, and you could try to insert a `B` in your array of `D` when you use it through a `B*`; this would compile, but fail again miserably at runtime.

In summary: don't try to use containers polymorphically for the reasons you see in your code.